# Windows Azure Active Directory - expiration of refreshtoken

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory

I am experimenting with Windows Azure Active Directory. In a client (desktop) application the user enter his credentials and authenticate to access a REST service. I'm using latest version of Active Directory Authentication Library. In my scenario I want that the user insert his credentials one time, so I store the refresh Token and use it to renew the access Token by calling AcquireTokenByRefreshToken method of AuthenticationContext object. 
My question is : Will the refreshtoken expire? Can I use the refreshtoken days or weeks after I obtained it?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to change the expiration?

Comment: AAD tokens expire after 1 hour. From the mastermind of AAD, "today there is no way of changing the default" https://twitter.com/vibronet/status/461260062204239872

Comment: @Daniele, how did you acquire new access token? did  you do it behind the scene? or the adal.js do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Refresh Token does expire.. I am not sure, but I believe you can set the TTL or expiration of the token in the setup of the WAAD properties on azure. I have to check, but I am not where I can access Azure at the moment.

Comment: https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/#comment-164

using Resource Explorer to manage your site’s auth settings, you can add a setting named “tokenRefreshExtensionHours” to {site}/config/authSettings.properties and set it to the number of hours to allow an expired token to be used for refresh.

Comment: There are news on this matter : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes

Answer (score 31):

I implemented the Azure AD SSO on mobile apps and used ADAL Nuget package. I had few queries from my clients on the expiration of the refresh-token. After going back and forth with Azure Engineering team, and trying few things, here are my findings. I have documented the details in a [blog post here](http://www.hasaltaiar.com.au/how-to-best-handle-aad-access-tokens-in-native-mobile-apps/):

1. Azure AD SSO **Access-Token expires in 1 hour**.
2. You could use Azure AD Refresh Token to refresh your AccessToken.
3. The **Refresh Token expires in 72**.
4. Azure allows an access-token to be refreshed **using the refresh-token for a maximum period of time of 90 days** (from the initial date of issuing the token). This means after 90 days, Azure will authenticate the user to login again. (Cannot confirm any changes to this)
5. The expiry time of the refresh token is set to 72 hours by default. This is now configurable. You can change this value as per the discussion [here](https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/#comment-164)

Full details can be found in [this blog post](http://www.hasaltaiar.com.au/how-to-best-handle-aad-access-tokens-in-native-mobile-apps/)

Comment: AITaiar any changes here that you know?

Comment: update the values above as per the discussion here: https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/#comment-164

Answer (score 2):

Solution is here.

[tokenRefreshExtensionHours](https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/#comment-164)

It is now configurable through App Service's Resource Manager to configure  tokenRefreshExtensionHours.

> "using Resource Explorer to manage your site’s auth settings, you can
>   add a setting named “tokenRefreshExtensionHours” to
>   {site}/config/authSettings.properties and set it to the number of
>   hours to allow an expired token to be used for refresh. "

Thanks to cgillum.

Answer (score 1):

I captured the calls to Azure Active Directory (AAD) with Fiddler and found a JSON response that included the access_token, expires_in and expires_on, id_token, refresh_token, resource, scope and token_type (Bearer).

The expires_on equals 1398790050. So I went to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1398790050+seconds+after+1970+%2B+2+hours), queried how many seconds this was after 1970 and added 2 hours (I'm in the UTC+2 time zone). The access token is valid for 1 hour. In the [TechNet forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/4ef35cd9-e689-4c85-971a-4443401e6ae3/waad-oauth-refresh-tokens-expiration?forum=windowsazuresecurity) it is mentioned the expire token is valid for about 80 days.

Answer (score 1):

The refresh token expiration time now can be configured officially :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the lifetime of tokens then keep in mind that Microsoft changed the bahviour for refresh and session tokens [as mentioned in official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-lifetime-policies-for-refresh-tokens-and-session-tokens):

```
As of January 30, 2021 you can not configure refresh and session token lifetimes.

You can still configure access, SAML, and ID token lifetimes...
```

Default lifetimes are mention in:

- [Access, ID, and SAML2 token lifetime policy properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-lifetime-policies-for-access-saml-and-id-tokens)
- [Token lifetime policies for refresh tokens and session tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-lifetime-policies-for-refresh-tokens-and-session-tokens)